# Make plot using groupby equivalent on powerbi

Tags: plot, group-by, powerbi

I have a table which contains a list of products scores by date:

[image]

From this table, have to make a plot of the porcentage of each quality by date.

I know how to do it in python but I´m having a hard time figuring out how to make it using power BI.

This is what I'm trying to make:

1)  Get the percentages by class:

[image]

I'm python this is easily done by grouping by date and score and divede it be a group by date:

```
df_grouped =  (df.groupby(["Date","Score"]).sum()/df.groupby(["Date"]).sum())*100
```

And then just make a plot of the percentage of each score by day

Like this:

[image]

How Can I get a similar result from powerbi?

Here is a google drive link to download a csv with the sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEdUwwofv1OQ9rOGQMuyfYKO9_YJDTcl/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:

I'm getting this result from M D code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new measure and change the data type of the measure to a percentage in the data modelling tab. The measure is to have the following DAX formula:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(sum(Table1[Percentage_By_Class]),filter(Table1,Table1[Date]=max(Table1[Date])),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Score]))/ CALCULATE(sum(Table1[Percentage_By_Class]),filter(all(Table1),Table1[Date]=max(Table1[Date])))
```

This will calculate the sum of a group (the score) by date and divide it by the total for all groups on the day. Then add it to a line chart with date as the axis, score as legend and the new measure as the values.

Review below images as well as the code.

[Graph Created With Your Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Btr.png)

Comment: But percentages áre wrong here, it adds up to more than 100%

Comment: Remove the *100 at the end of my measure and convert the data type of the measure to a percentage in the data modelling tab. I have modified my original post. Please indicate it if the correct answer if this solves your problem to assist others in the future.

Comment: I updated the question with your answer, which seems to be right. But the you you share it´s different. Please update it to approve the answer

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect what is seen with your sample data. It looks like it is working correctly :) .

Comment: I tried this same script on a bigger table, when I add the scores to the filters then the plot does not load. It is just "loading" forever. Any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: Hi Luis, are you importing the data via data import or direct query and how many rows are you trying to plot?

Comment: Yes, via direct query. There are only few thousand, it seems to be an issue with the dates format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188771/discussion-between-m-d-and-luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez).